# Integral surface $(S) =(x=u+2v,y= u^2-v^2,z= uv+5)$.

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Calculate the area of ​​the surface S defined by $$(S) =S=\begin{cases}
 & \text{ } x=u+2v  \\ 
 & \text{  } y= u^2-v^2 \\ 
 & \text{  } z= uv+5
\end{cases}$$ where $$A(S)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{(C)} xdy.ydx$$ and $$(u,v)\in R^2$$.I think of Green-Riemann Theorem but how to know if the curve is a closed one?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Use the [area formula of a parametric surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area#General_formula_for_surface_area) in the vector form 
$$\mathbf{r}=(x,y,z)=(u+2v,u^2-v^2,uv+5)$$
and
$$A=\iint_{D}\left| \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial v}\right|\,du\,dv.$$
but here we need $D$ to find $A$!

Comment: How to find D? (S) is not well defined and $(u,v)\in R^2$

Comment: Here $D$ is an infinite shape, such that $y$ and $z$ give a hyperbola shape so the problem is incomplete, I think.